# Wordpress create page from plugin with custom template

Tags: wordpress

I have created a page successfully from my custom plugin and have successfully added a custom template to the template dropdown and associated successfully the template to that page.

The problem is that the template is not being loaded.

Here the code

```
$new_page = array(
    'post_title' => __( 'Custom Page' ),
    'post_name' => 'custom-page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'post_content' => '',
    'menu_order' => 0,
    // Assign page template
    'page_template' => plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/my-plugin-folder/my-plugin-custom-template.php'
);

// insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $new_page );
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: First check on the body tag which template loaded for the page.

Comment: it's loading the normal theme page template page.php. But the page has my custom template selected.

Comment: Any Ideas? I really need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

when page load will be searching for my-plugin-custom-template.php in the theme directory, so you will have to redirect that to your plugin directory by using the page_template filter like below the code.

```
 function custom_redirect_page_template ($template) {
        $post = get_post(); 
        $page_template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ); 
        if ('my-plugin-custom-template.php' == basename ($page_template ))
            $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my-plugin-folder/my-plugin-custom-template.php';
        return $template;
        }
    add_filter ('page_template', 'custom_redirect_page_template');
```

Comment: But isn't there a way to set it on creation?